# Two non-negative numbers cannot be zero at the same time

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How to write a symbol showing that two non-negative numbers cannot be zero at the same time? Can I write:

$a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \sim(a=b=0)$

or

$a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \setminus(a=b=0)$

or

$A=\{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\}\setminus(a=b=0)$?

This is intended for applied statisticians who might not be too familiar with analysis.

Comment: How about $a+b>0?$

Comment: $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\text{ s.t.} \lnot a=b=0$ perhaps.

Comment: I think sometimes it is best _not_ to use symbols alone to convey something. That is, with respect to your comment "this is intended for [...]".

Comment: You could use $a^2+b^2 \neq0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try
$$ (a,b) \in (\mathbb R_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb R_{\geq 0})\setminus\{(0,0)\}.$$

But your last example is probably a more accessible style,
which could be modified to either

$$ \{(a,b) : a, b \in\mathbb R_{\geq 0} \}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$$

or perhaps even more clearly

$$ \{(a,b) : a, b \in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}, \lnot (a = b = 0)\}.$$

Or perhaps just "$a, b$ two non-negative real numbers, not both zero"
if you don't absolutely need it to be a formula.